# Codeigniter displays nothing when attempting to upload a file

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload

I'm having a problem uploading files in CodeIgniter. This is my autoload: `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'file');`

I have echoed out the `realpath(APPPATH . '../images');` and it is the right location. When I click submit, nothing happens and no error is shown; it just reloads the view.

Model:

```
<?php
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model{

var $gallery_path;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');

}

function do_upload()
{

    //handle userfile
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path

    );


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();

}


}

?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Gallery extends CI_Controller
{
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Gallery_model');
    if($this->input->post('upload'))
    {
        //handle upload
        $this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
    }

    $this->load->view('gallery');
}


}


?>
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>Gallery</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="gallery">

</div>

<div id="upload">

<?php

echo form_open_multipart('gallery');
echo form_upload('userfile');
echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
echo form_close();
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have `$this->upload->do_upload()`, replace that with:

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
{
    die($this->upload->display_errors());
}
```

So that you can find out what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure " The path to the folder where the upload should be placed. The folder must be writable and the path can be absolute or relative. "

I just copy the code, and image can be upload.

Comment: so it worked for you? the place is correct I checked it by echoeing it out, I am pretty sure it is writeable but I will have a look, does it need to be 777?

Also what is absolute or relative path?

Comment: folder need to be 777.  and i make the path 'upload_path' => 'public/uploads/' in my code , where relative with the index.php

Comment: Thanks again for your help you were right, but I couldnt find out unless I had the guys code at the top it seems forcing CI to show errors, but thank you both lots!